# Div stay inside containment and be resizeable, keeping containment

Tags: jquery

I want to resize my div with an id of `#box`, but when I resize my box, it changes the containment. How can I resize my box, and keep the containment from moving?

```js
$(function() {
  $(".size").resizable();
});
$(function() {
  $(".size").draggable({
    containment: [0, 50, 700, 150]
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  padding: 200px 120px;
  background: #888;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0 1px 0 rgba(200, 200, 200, .5);
  border: 1px solid rgba(3, 3, 3, .5);
  left: -1px;
  top: 50px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="box" class="size">
</div>
```

This is what the code looks on mine, but I'm getting a few errors on here. So, can I resize it without moving the containment? It would also be nice it this could apply to all screen sizes. (Monitors)

Comment: Just FYI your fiddle was broken as you included jQueryUI *before* jQuery itself. I fixed it for you in this example. You should check you haven't got the same problem in your actual code.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering about that problem. Yeah, that's not my problem though.  The resize is not working for some reason though.